# fail2ban keeps saying already banned but it didn't actually ban

Tags: linux, ssh, fail2ban

I just configured a new server and installed fail2ban as well, but it is not banning me when I keep trying to connect with the wrong password

fail2ban.log:

```
2018-03-23 12:46:29,363 fail2ban.actions        [9756]: NOTICE  [sshd] [my ip] already banned
2018-03-23 12:46:30,747 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:46:33,346 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:46:35,515 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:46:36,372 fail2ban.actions        [9756]: NOTICE  [sshd] [my ip] already banned
2018-03-23 12:47:45,471 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:47:46,820 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:47:49,503 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:47:50,458 fail2ban.actions        [9756]: NOTICE  [sshd] [my ip] already banned
2018-03-23 12:47:51,893 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:48:49,699 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:48:51,835 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:48:52,531 fail2ban.actions        [9756]: NOTICE  [sshd] [my ip] already banned
2018-03-23 12:48:54,477 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:48:57,056 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:50:53,240 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:50:53,677 fail2ban.actions        [9756]: NOTICE  [sshd] [my ip] already banned
2018-03-23 12:50:55,065 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:50:58,253 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:51:00,494 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:51:00,685 fail2ban.actions        [9756]: NOTICE  [sshd] [my ip] already banned
2018-03-23 12:52:06,119 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:52:08,300 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:52:11,583 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:52:11,773 fail2ban.actions        [9756]: NOTICE  [sshd] [my ip] already banned
2018-03-23 12:52:13,498 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:53:07,823 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:53:09,712 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:53:09,842 fail2ban.actions        [9756]: NOTICE  [sshd] [my ip] already banned
2018-03-23 12:53:11,718 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:53:13,696 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:54:37,181 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:54:37,949 fail2ban.actions        [9756]: NOTICE  [sshd] [my ip] already banned
2018-03-23 12:54:39,092 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:54:40,906 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:54:42,616 fail2ban.filter         [9756]: INFO    [sshd] Found [my ip]
2018-03-23 12:54:42,955 fail2ban.actions        [9756]: NOTICE  [sshd] [my ip] already banned
2018-03-23 12:54:52,074 fail2ban.action         [9756]: ERROR   iptables -w -n -L INPUT | grep -q 'f2b-sshd[ \t]' -- stdout: ''
2018-03-23 12:54:52,075 fail2ban.action         [9756]: ERROR   iptables -w -n -L INPUT | grep -q 'f2b-sshd[ \t]' -- stderr: ''
2018-03-23 12:54:52,075 fail2ban.action         [9756]: ERROR   iptables -w -n -L INPUT | grep -q 'f2b-sshd[ \t]' -- returned 1
2018-03-23 12:54:52,075 fail2ban.CommandAction  [9756]: ERROR   Invariant check failed. Trying to restore a sane environment
2018-03-23 12:54:52,180 fail2ban.action         [9756]: ERROR   iptables -w -D INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j f2b-sshd
iptables -w -F f2b-sshd
iptables -w -X f2b-sshd -- stdout: ''
2018-03-23 12:54:52,181 fail2ban.action         [9756]: ERROR   iptables -w -D INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j f2b-sshd
iptables -w -F f2b-sshd
iptables -w -X f2b-sshd -- stderr: "iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load target `f2b-sshd':No such file or directory\n\nTry `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.\niptables: No chain/target/match by that name.\niptables: No chain/target/match by that name.\n"
2018-03-23 12:54:52,181 fail2ban.action         [9756]: ERROR   iptables -w -D INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j f2b-sshd
iptables -w -F f2b-sshd
iptables -w -X f2b-sshd -- returned 1
2018-03-23 12:54:52,181 fail2ban.actions        [9756]: ERROR   Failed to execute unban jail 'sshd' action 'iptables-multiport' info '{'matches': '2018-03-23T11:53:46.707058149-210-194-176.colo.transip.net sshd[27676]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=ip-[my ip].ip.prioritytelecom.net  user=root2018-03-23T11:53:48.733188149-210-194-176.colo.transip.net sshd[27676]: Failed password for root from [my ip] port 31224 ssh22018-03-23T11:54:51.709842149-210-194-176.colo.transip.net sshd[27676]: Failed password for root from [my ip] port 31224 ssh2', 'ip': '[my ip]', 'time': 1521802491.930057, 'failures': 3}': Error stopping action
```

When I tail the log file, I see my ssh login attempts getting logged, but after the 3rd attempt I just can keep trying; if I use the right password after the 10th attempt, for example, it will log me in.

I also get errors, seen at the end of the log file, every now and then.

my jail.local:

```
[DEFAULT]
#ban n hosts for one hour:
bantime = 3600

#maxtrys
maxretry = 3

# Override /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/00-firewalld.conf:
banaction = iptables-multiport

[sshd]
enabled = true
```

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Comment: you have got there an error in English complaining about of lack of a chain in    iptables

Comment: this is the first time ever I work with linux so I got no clue what that would mean. Is there anything I can do against that?

Comment: Away from computer. You have got to create a new iptables chain by the name in the error message

Comment: this file ? iptables-multiport

Comment: @Kiwy what do you mean with this file? do I need to run `vi iptables-multiport` on the location where fail2ban expects it to be or?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like your `iptables` configuration does not include a filter chain named `f2b-sshd`.

First, a mini-primer on `iptables`.

`iptables` is both a command and the name of the Linux firewall subsystem. The command is used to set up firewall rules in RAM. The `iptables` firewall rules are arranged first into tables: there is the default `filter` table, but also `nat`, `mangle`, `raw` and `security` tables, for various purposes. `fail2ban` is doing traffic filtering, so it uses the `filter` table.

The tables are then further divisible into filter chains. Each table has certain standard chains: for the `filter` table, the standard chains are `INPUT`, `FORWARD` and `OUTPUT`. The `FORWARD` chain is only used when the system is configured to route traffic for other systems. The `INPUT` chain deals with incoming traffic to this system.

If `fail2ban` added its rules directly to the `INPUT` chain and wiped that chain clean when all the bans expired, then you would have to turn over full control of your firewall input rules to `fail2ban` - you could not easily have any custom firewall rules *in addition to* what `fail2ban` does. This is clearly not desirable, so `fail2ban` won't do that.

Instead, `fail2ban` creates its own filter chain it can fully manage on its own, and adds on start-up a single rule to the `INPUT` chain to send any matching traffic to be processed through `fail2ban`'s chain.

For example, when configured to protect `sshd`, `fail2ban` should be executing these commands at start-up:

```
iptables -N f2b-sshd
iptables -A f2b-sshd -j RETURN
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports <TCP ports configured for sshd protection> -j f2b-sshd
```

These commands create a `f2b-sshd` filter chain, set `RETURN` as its last rule (so that when any `fail2ban` rules have been processed, the normal processing of INPUT rules will continue as without `fail2ban`, and finally, add a rule to the beginning of the `INPUT` table to catch any SSH traffic and send it first to the `f2b-sshd` chain.

Now, when `fail2ban` needs to ban an IP address for SSH use, it will just insert a new rule to the `f2b-sshd` chain.

If you are using `firewalld` or some other system that manages iptables firewall rules for you, or if you clear all the `iptables` rules manually, then these initial rules, and possibly the entire `f2b-sshd` filter chain, may be wiped out. You should make sure that any firewall management tool you might be using maintains that initial rule in the INPUT chain and doesn't touch the `f2b-sshd` chain at all.

The error messages at the end of your snippet indicate that `fail2ban` is checking that the initial rules are still there ("invariant check"), and finding that they're not.

Answer (score 2):

the problem was, that the ban was working, but the attacker was using persistent connections so the ban was not in effect right away, as it was still connected and there was no new connection, the only way to do when it was happening restart the mail server

Comment: I had the same problem, restarting postfix was what worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

i just had to deal with this.  the problem was related to following an exim4 fail2ban tutorial.  the jail.d/exim4.conf file had this:

```
[exim-spam]
port = smtp,ssmtp
```

where what is actually needed, because exim4 is running on ports 25, 464 *and* 587, was this:

```
[exim-spam]
port = smtp,ssmtp,587
```

that's all it is.

basically, all the filters are correctly set up, everything is working... however:

- the attacks come in on port 587
- and fail2ban is instructed - by the config file - to block ONLY ports 25 and 465

therefore, of course the attacks continue!  so, adapt that to the protocol that you're using (sshd in this case).

"netstat -an | more" and "iptables -L -n" and "lsof -i :587" are your friends, here.